# Beamer - undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer

I have been using beamer for some time now with TexnicCenter. Recently I updated  operating system to Windows 7, TexnicCenter and also MikTeX (I try to run the code with both  MikTex 2.8 and MikTeX 2.9).
Every presentation (even the old ones, which were working perfectly before updates) gives me an error warning and the created pdf file has extra slides with just numbers in the top left corner.

The basic TeX file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
abc
\end{frame}
\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And the error message:

```
Undefined control sequence:
\beamer@frameslide ...duration=}\thispdfpagelabel
{\insertframenumber}\xda.....
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

The log file can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxtnIhcRVe2wZjYzMDBkOGEtOTcwOS00Mzg1LTgzOGQtYTZiMjE1M2YyNWY0&hl=en&authkey=CLjF0IIJ). The code written above produce just on error message.

Comment: Work for me (TeX Live 2010). Try deleting any .aux file in the directory.

Comment: Caramdir, thanks, but your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you post (include in the question or link to it if it's too big) the complete log file?  Try to compile, and hit 's' at the first error so it will run without pausing at each error.  I have a suspicion that because of your recent upgrade you are loading parts of beamer from different distributions/releases.

Comment: The link to log file is added below the question. I also suspect that something is wrong because of updates but I'm not able to figure it out where is the problem. I reinstall both Miktex (complete version) and TexnicCenter.

Comment: What does the second option on the `\begin{frame}{?}` do?

Comment: @Seamus: It sets the frame title.

Comment: @Caramdir huh. I didn't know that. I've been using `\frametitle` all this time...

Comment: I get the same error with current pgf 2.10 and beamer 3.10 in MiKTeX 2.8. Seems it is not fixed yet. The workaround however works, but I don't want to leave it in my source code. :-/

Comment: @LeSpocky: Welcome! If you've got a question, then you should ask it in a new post. Please do this with the "Ask Question" link. In your new question you can link to this one.

Comment: Just a note to confirm Hendrik's comment, this ought to be reposted as a question for you to get the best chance of it being answered.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are not using the newest beamer version. The newest in miktex is beamer 2010/06/21 development version 3.10. Your version is beamer 2007/03/11 cvs version 3.07. As you have beamer in one of your user roots, you will probably have to run the update manager in user mode to get the newest version, or [manually download the newest version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/archive/master.zip).

The error message itself is a bug in beamer. I have seen a posting about it 2 or 3 ago. `\thispdfpagelabel` is defined by hyperref only if `pagelabels=true`, but beamer used it also in dvi-mode. The problem has been obviously corrected. I don't get an error.

If you don't want to update you can try

```
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
```

Comment: Umm ... "2 or three" what "ago"? `:)` (You're missing a word, probably months or years.)

Comment: Great!  The `\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}` workaround worked for me!  Needed the `hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}` document class option to prevent warnings on a machine using Beamer 3.07 and TeXworks 0.2.3 (using pdfLaTeX to typeset).  Then, because of said option, I needed said workaround to prevent an error on a machine using Beamer 3.10 and TeXworks 0.5 (again using pdfLaTex to typeset).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but solved it by removing `hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}` from the options to the document class.