# beamer doesn't work after upgrading to MiKTeX 2.9 – 20 error messages

Tags: beamer, errors, miktex

After upgrading to MiKTeX 2.9 my `beamer` files stopped working.  The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
Hello 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Gives some 20 errors and two warnings, the first error being:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...eamer@linkspace {6pt}\Hy@xspace@end 
                             \Hy@LinkMath \Hy@SaveSpace...
```

and the first warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 3.
```

The log file is available [here](http://www.divshare.com/download/14568814-3cb).

I have searched the web in vain, for example tried deleting the .aux file as suggested at [Beamer - undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/beamer-undefined-control-sequence), the solutions did not work.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the `hyperref` package which is loaded by `beamer`.

Answer (score 3):

update the package `hyperref`. If it is not available with MiKTeX (for TeXLive it was updated yesterday) try in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter\def\Hy@xspace@end{}\makeatother
```

Comment: The \makeatletter\def\Hy@xspace@end{}\makeatother did work! Thank you!!

Updating the hyperref and \def\Hy@xspace@end{} did not work, but the newest update of hyperref that I could find was from 14. of april (not yesterday).